# Automatically send an email with list of corresponding values in column A when value in column D= todays date for each sheet in workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that has multiple worksheets, and each sheet has a 'last updated' column in column D. I want to automatically send a daily email that outputs the cell value in column A (which is a simple string) when the corresponding date in column D = todays date, and do that for every sheet in the workbook.

Comment: You will probably get a lot of flak for not supplying code you've tried. Try going here to get started: https://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/send-email.htm

Comment: You can easily send emails if you have outlook set up on your machine, just add a reference to MS Outlook to your vba project (to help you with autocompletion). No outlook? try using CDO as in https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/cdo.htm . As @Mech hinted you need to update your question with some code you tried.